# What is the Thevenin Norton equivalent of the folloing circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, norton

I am trying to find the Thevenin Norton equivalent of the folloing circuit. I am familiar with the procedure.
However, when I am taking off the voltages to calculate the equivalent resistance, I am not sure how to deal with the fact that instead of the voltages I get two branches on the sides, with no resistors at all..

Any help will be most welcome

Thanks

[image]

*Edit*: I am looking for both Thevenin and Norton equivalent. But any of them will help. Also, The middle resistor is Rload=$R_L$. This is where I need to measure resistance, Voltage and current. I.e "what does RL see"?

Comment: Looks  like you could split it into two  separate circuits since it doesn't look like anything flows over that middle resistor.

Comment: Are you looking for the Thévenin equivalent or the Norton equivalent? They're two different things.

Comment: Where are you taking your output? And I'd suggest re-entering the circuit using the built in schematic editor, this is quite hard to read as it is.

Comment: I am looking for both Norton and Thevenin

Comment: The middle resistor is Rload=$R_L$. This is where I need to measure resistance, Voltage and current. I.e "what does RL see"?

Comment: Did your professor mention anything about lines of symmetry in a circuit?

Comment: If you anyone could explain what are " lines of symmetry in a circuit" I wiil be greratfull. Dont recall my professor talking about it but maybe he did and I dont remember